# How to compare a parsed string object within a predicate to the predicate string

Tags: c#, string, compare, predicate

I have this code(heavily modified for your comfort):

```cs
string password = Console.ReadLine();
var checker = new Predicate<string>[] { (s) => s == password };
string password2 = CompareStringAgainstPredicatesAndReturn(checker);
```

The predicate's purpose is to verify that password2 is the same as password. Yet I am getting the following error message:
CS1628: Cannot use ref, out, or in parameter 'password' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local function

I don't know how to parse a variable to the predicate. So how would I go about doing this?

*Gonna point out one more time that this is not the actual code. The question is **only** regarding the actual predicate situation.*

As I was afraid, the lack of a complete code caused confusion and understandable misunderstandings. Therefore, here is the full code

```cs
string password = BInput.GetPredicateString(
new string[] { "Choose your password" },
"Password: ", //Simply a prompt
"Your password needs to be between 8 to 30 characters long, contain at least 2 numbers and at least one special character", // Error message
new Predicate<string>[] {
        (s) => s.Length > 8,
        (s) => s.Length < 30,
        (s) => s == password,
        (s) => Verificator.ContainsSpecialCharacter(s) //Not native
    }
);
```

BInput.GetPredicateString will confirm that the returned string fulfills all requirements within the predicate. This is why the Predicate is an array.

Hoping this brings more clarity, but it's fully possible it doesn't as I've been programming now for 14 hours and brain is like a soggy sponge.

Best regards,

Comment: This code compiles fine (after adding a type on `password`) if you throw it into a new console app.  It looks like you are passing `password` as a `ref` or `out` parameter, which the error is specifically telling you about.  Also why are you creating an array of predicates?

Comment: and password2 is not consumed?

Comment: @Jonesopolis It is getting used. As stated, this is just about the predicate. It's just not getting used in the very short sample code. Password is parsed to the method as method(out string password), so it has a type. I've now added an extra part of the code, but it's not feasible to add everything. The sample code was only meant to show the specific error with the predicate. But I've noticed that clarifications are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you updated the question with more info, here is how I would check with a predicate array:

```
string? password = Console.ReadLine();
string? password2 = Console.ReadLine();

Predicate<string>[] checker = new Predicate<string>[] {
        (s) => s.Length > 8,
        (s) => s.Length < 30,
        (s) => s == password
    };

//when validated, this line can be used inside your GetPredicateString method
//password2 can be passed as parameter to GetPredicateString method.
var isPasswordValid = checker.All(predicate => predicate(password2));
```

Here I use All method to check all predicates are true.

So if I pass

```
password 123456789 and password2 123456789 => will be true
password 123456789 and password2 123456788 => will be false
password 1234567 and password2 1234567 => will be false
password 123456789012345678901234567890 and password2 123456789012345678901234567890 => will be false
```

One thing more to mention. In your variable `String password...` it contains also a condition`s == password`, this will fail because the variable name and variable input can not have the same name.

So you need to change `String password =..` to `String passwordPredicated =..` or something like that.

**Original Answer**

I am not sure why you are using array in predicted, but if you need to check one input against the other input, by using a predicate, you can do something like this:

```
string? password = Console.ReadLine();
string? password2 = Console.ReadLine();

Predicate<string> checker = new Predicate<string>(s => s == password);

bool isEqual = checker(password2);
```

Make 2 equal inputs and you get True else it will be false.

Comment: So I've added more information to the question, yet I am unsure if it's clear. I will check this thread in the morning and see if I've come up with a better example as the password one doesn't work anyways.

Comment: I can see you have update your question since my answer,  I will see if I can look at it at some point tomorrow it is late night 

Answer (score 0):

The class `Predicate` is a generic one.
You can create a class that encapsulates both passwords and use it with `Predicate` class.

```
class BothPasswords {
   public string Password1 { get; set; }
   public string Password2 { get; set; }
}
```

So, in the main method you will have, for example:

```
string password1 = "test";
string password2 = "test";

Predicate<BothPasswords> isUpper = objParam => objParam.Password1.Equals(objParam.Password2.ToUpper());
bool result = isUpper(new BothPasswords { Password1 = password1, Password2 = password2 });
```

Comment: So I've added more information to the question, yet I am unsure if it's clear. I will check this thread in the morning and see if I've come up with a better example as the password one doesn't work anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can use ref, out etc. Inside a lambda body.

Use a temp variable to store ref or
Use a simple extension methods and chain them for this case.

```
public static class PasswordValidator ...
  public static bool HasValidLength(this string password)
   { 
      [condition to check] 
   }
```